# Multiple linear regression machine learning can work well with high-dimensional data?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, least-squares, high-dimensional

My data and problem:

- Data is high-dimensional data with 15474 features (columns) and 375 cases (observations, rows). Data contains 34% zero values.
- Output/response is multiple outputs of 2 (continuous values).

Many researchers said that this high-dimensional data is unsuitable with multiple linear regression algorithms.

But, I compared different machine learning models (such as linear regression, Support Vector Regression, Automatic Relevance Determination, Huber regression, random forest, and Gradient Boosting for regression) and found that multiple linear regression (Ordinary least squares) is the best one.

I used techniques to avoid overfitting and data leakage while training models, such as 1) split: train, validation, and test data; 2) standardized and nested cross-validation; 3) using pipeline in Python; 4) test data was held out to finally test...

So, can I ignore the term "high dimensional data" and accept the comparative results using a "try and error" approach?

Or Are there any comments or explanations for my problem?

Comment: Wow, you must be a prophet. I would expect a lot of issues with such an approach. By the way, how did you use OLS and the other models when you have 2 outputs?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! 1) How are you fitting the ordinary least squares regression? The typical approach involves inverting a matrix that will not be invertible for your data that has more features than observations. // 2) What do you mean that the output/response is multiple outputs of two?

Comment: I fit the model by MultiOutputRegressor in Sklearn through chain model and non-chain model.

Comment: Multiple outputs of two means that there are two outputs that have to predict and I predicted two output variables at the same time by chain model. 

Brief code:
LR= make_pipeline(StandardScaler(),LinearRegression());
model = MultiOutputRegressor(estimator=LR);
n_scores = cross_val_score(model, xtrain, ytrain, cv=cv)

Comment: Could you explain more "The typical approach involves inverting a matrix that will not be invertible for your data that has more features than observations"?

Comment: $\hat\beta_{ols}=(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty$. If that $X^TX$ is not invertible, which it will not be when $X$ has more rows that columns like you have, that usual estimator cannot be calculated. Therefore, some alternative approach is required. Which alternative are you using?

Comment: In fact, I do not know in detail how to deal with the inverse matrix here. I guess Sklearn address automatically simultaneous linear equations.